# Is it OK to pass the concrete client to a method on the concrete strategy?

Tags: design-patterns, strategy

When using the strategy pattern, is it good practice to pass `this` to a method on `this.strategy`?

I have a strategy interface with one call, `TakeAction`.  The idea is that TakeAction decides which of the several possible actions the Client should perform and then calls the appropriate method on the client.  So in a concrete strategy, the `TakeAction` method might look like:

```
void TakeAction(IAbstractClient client)
{
    if (client.IsBlah()) client.UnBlah(this.BlahValue1, this.BlahValue2);
    else if (client.CanFoo()) client.Foo(this.FooValue);
    else if (this.ShouldTwiddle()) client.Twiddle();
}
```

And in the client, the call looks like:

```
this.strategy.TakeAction(this);
```

Is this good form?  Or is there a better way to do this?  (Passing back a class with an enum describing the action and the values to pass to it seemed overkill.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Passing `this` to a strategy is perfectly fine. This lets you use polymorphism as intended.

So long as the class implements the `IAbstractClient` interface, you are good to go.